# Unexpected return of async/ await function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await

The scraper I am making has a register route to start the scraping process. Since the scraping process is very long, I decided to create another route that my front-end will make a request to every 15 seconds to get the data. The problem I am encountering is that the route to get the data is returning an empty object even when the scraping is done. In reality, it should have returned the scraped data and NOT have returned a 404 error (refer to code below). I have included extra code in case it is the cause of the problem.

```
const scraper = async (email, password) => {
  let grades = [[], [], [], []];
  let category_weights = [];
  try {
    // try to scrape website
    // this block of code contains await functions
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return;
  } finally {
    return {
      grades,
      category_weights
    };
  }
};

let result;

app.post("/api/register", (req, res) => {
  result = scraper(req.body.email, req.body.password);
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.get("/api/data", (req, res) => {
  console.log(result["grades"]); // undefined
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4)); // {}
  result.hasOwnProperty("grades") ? res.json(result) : res.sendStatus(404);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is returning **404** status code because `result` is a `Promise`, and it does not have `grades` property.

You have to wait until the promise is done. You can use `await` for that. That way, once the scraper is done, calls to `/api/data` will return the data, instead of a **404** status code.

In order to avoid the timeout issue, you can either increase the timeout for that specific route:

```
req.setTimeout(1000 * 60 * 5); // or whatever value you want
```

Or just end the request as soon as `/api/register` is hit, and then run the scraper function, awaiting the result.

```
app.post("/api/register", async(req, res) => {

    res.sendStatus(200);

    try {
        result = await scraper(req.body.email, req.body.password);

    } catch(e) {
        console.log('Scraper failed');
    }

});

app.get("/api/data", (req, res) => {
  console.log(result["grades"]); // undefined
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4)); // {}
  result.hasOwnProperty("grades") ? res.json(result) : res.sendStatus(404);
});
```

And here's proof that `JSON.stringify` on a `Promise` will return `{}`

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(new Promise(() => {}), null, 4)); // {}
```

Comment: If I use async/await in the register route, the request will be too long (as stated in the question), and therefore, timeout.

Comment: Oh. I thought that when res was called, the function returned, so the remaining code wouldn't be executed. My bad.

Comment: No, you can end the request, and keep doing things.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the previous comment. Also, I can't use req.setTimeout because heroku limits timeouts, too (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout).

Comment: Okay, I see. Then go with the other approach. What I meant was. if you don't want to call `scraper` again if it's still processing. You have to add a flag and check if it's processing and do nothing. If it's not scraping, then scrape.

Comment: Oh. That makes sense. Thank you for your assistance.